# Pigeonhole principle in practice?

Tags: combinatorics

Does one have an example of how to calculate stuff using the Pigeonhole principle?
Lets say I have 200 students that are doing a test(with a grade from 0-100) how can I know how many(minimum) will receive the same grade?

I know that the max will be 200 and that obviously there will be some duplicated grades but how can i calculate how many duplicates I **must** have?

Comment: Pigeonhole principle won't tell you the no. of duplicates you **must** have. It will only tell you the **least** no. of duplicates you **must** have

Comment: To answer your first question: [yes](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4279/interesting-applications-of-the-pigeon-hole-principle).

Comment: Are you asking "how many grades will be obtained by more than one student?" or "how many students will obtain a grade that someone else also achieved?" It's not clear to me from what you wrote.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Hmm actually it looks for me like you asked the same question twice, Im asking how many students (at least) will get the exact same grade

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Oh i now see the difference yea my bad thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a principle known as the Generalized Pidgeonhole Principle which states that if $nk+1$ objects are packed into $n$ boxes then one box must have at least $k+1$ objects. In your case, you have 101 boxes and 200 objects. Now 200 is not quite 101*2+1, thus we can't conclude that there must be at least 3 grades that are the same. However, you are packing 101*1+1 into 101 boxes, thus we can conclude that there are at least 2 grades that are the same.

Here's a formula. Assume we are packing $m$ objects across $n$ boxes. Then *at least one* box must have *at least* $\lceil m/n \rceil$ objects.

Comment: There are actually 101 "boxes".

Comment: That's right. Simple mistake.

Comment: @Bryan So if i got it right in case of 350 students it will be 350 objects which are packed into 101 boxes -> 101*4+1 is bigger than 350 thus it means i'll have at least 4 grades that are the same?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Make sure that the $k$ you chose is the *least* $k$ such that $nk+1$ surpasses your number of objects.

Comment: Thanks now i understand how to approach this kind of problems :)

Comment: One question about your last edit, m / n in my case is 350 / 101 which is ~3, so why I have at least 4 objects and not 3(look at my previous comment)?

Comment: The delimiters are important. $\lceil \;\rceil$ is the ceiling function. This means round up. So, 350/101 is a little over 3, thus we round up to 4.

Comment: Oh i see didn't know that thanks :)